# como solucionar un error al calcular percentiles en r

Tags: r

tengo una base de datos gigante, y necisto calcular el decil y percentil de unas columnas, todos los valores son numéricos , pero cuando corro este codigo me aparece un error

```
ptje2021<- ptje2021 %>%
  mutate(Percentile_Math=quantile(Math_Score1, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/100), na.rm = TRUE, ))%>%
           mutate(Decile_Math=quantile(Math_Score1, na.rm = TRUE, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/10))
```

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Percentile_Math`.
ℹ `Percentile_Math = quantile(...)`.
ℹ `Percentile_Math` must be size 308535 or 1, not 101.
Backtrace:
 1. `%>%`(...)
 7. dplyr:::abort_glue(character(0), list(x_size = 101L), "dplyr:::mutate_incompatible_size")
 8. rlang::exec(abort, class = class, !!!data)
```

según diversas paginas esa era la forma correcta de sacar deciles y percentiles en r, pero no se porqué me esta arrojado ese error, apreciaría si me pueden ayudar.

lo que necesito es que esta nueva columna de percentiles se añada a mi dataframe original y no se cree una nueva tabla, intenté con summarise en vez de mutate, pero me genera una nueva tabla con los percentiles de 101 columnas y necesito que esto encaje con mi dataframe original que tiene 300000 datos.

Comment: Reemplaza el `mutate` por `summarise`, ¿eso es lo que buscas?

Comment: lo intenté pero me crea una nueva tabla y lo que necesito es que esta nueva columna se añada a mi dataframe original coincidiendo con los. numero de fila, ya que la data original tiene aprox 300000 filas y la resultante de percentil tiene 101

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, el calculo de los percentiles lo haces sobre todos los valores de una columna, por ejemplo Math_Score1, esto te devolvería 101 valores ¿dónde quieres poner estos 101 valores?

Comment: claro, el claculo de los percentiles es sobre toda la columna de math_sore1 que pertenece a un dataframe, en total son aproximadamente 300000 filas, y al  calcular los percentiles, me entrega 101 datos, lo que necesito es que se cree una nueva columa con estos 101 datos en el dataframe original, pero la diferencia de datos es un problema por que no coincide el numero

Comment: Ese es quid de la cuestión, tienes los percentiles que es un sumario del data.frame, ¿cómo buscas acomodar esos valores en el df original? ¿quieres que esos 101 valores se repitan en las 308535 filas?

Comment: no, lo que quiero es que a cada valor de math score, se le asigne un valor del percentil

Comment: Ahhh, queres saber a que percentil de la muetrsa completa  corresponde cada valor, ahora sí.

Comment: exacto, pero de la forma que lo estoy intentando no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber a que percentil corresponde cada valor, puedes usar la función `cut()`, por ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(percentile = cut(disp,
                          unique(
                            quantile(disp,
                                     probs = seq(0, 1, 1/100), 
                                     na.rm = TRUE)),
                          include.lowest = TRUE)
         ) %>% 
  select(percentile) %>% 
  head() # A modo de ejemplo solo muestro los primeros casos

                     percentile
Mazda RX4           (157.1,160]
Mazda RX4 Wag       (157.1,160]
Datsun 710        (107.5,111.3]
Hornet 4 Drive    (249.4,258.9]
Hornet Sportabout   (357.6,360]
Valiant             (214.1,229]
```

Esto te retorna el "rango" dónde se ubica cada valor en los percentiles, no es más que un factor que podrías convertir a numérico para saber que percentil es:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(percentile = cut(disp,
                          unique(
                            quantile(disp,
                                     probs = seq(0, 1, 1/100), 
                                     na.rm = TRUE)),
                          include.lowest = TRUE),
         percentile = as.numeric(percentile)
         ) %>% 
  select(percentile) %>% 
  head() # A modo de ejemplo solo muestro los primeros casos

                  percentile
Mazda RX4                 39
Mazda RX4 Wag             39
Datsun 710                17
Hornet 4 Drive            51
Hornet Sportabout         75
Valiant                   48
```